# Determining a spanning set for $X/\bigcap_{i=1}^N \ker{\lambda_i}$, where each $\lambda_i$ is a linear functional on $X$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $X$ be a vector space over a field $K$. Suppose that $\{\lambda_i\}_{i=1}^N$ is a collection of linear functionals $\lambda_i : X \to K$. Let  $W$ be the subspace  $\{ x \in X \mid \lambda_i(x) = 0, i = 1, \dots, N \}$.

Now, let us consider the quotient $K$-vector space $X/W$. Then each map $\overline{\lambda}_i : X/W \to K$ given by $\overline{\lambda}_i(x + W) = \lambda_i(x)$ is well-defined and linear.

> I would like to show that the $K$-vector space of linear functionals $X/W \to K$ is spanned by the maps $\overline{\lambda}_i.$

This assertion (or at least a variant of it), is made at the end of the proof of Theorem IV.20 in Reed and Simon's [Methods of Modern Mathematical Physics, Vol.1](http://books.google.com/books/about/Methods_of_Modern_Mathematical_Physics_F.html?id=fXX0j4qa8G8C). The authors claim that the fact above follows from "basic abstract algbera." Although I feel comfortable with beginner's abstract algebra, I am struggling to come up with a proof.

I know that I need to take an arbitrary functional $l$ on $X/W$ and show that there exist $\alpha_i \in K$ such that $l(x + W) = \sum_{i=1}^N \alpha_i \overline{\lambda}_i (x + W)$ for all $x \in X.$ I've also noticed that $W = \bigcap_{i=1}^N \ker{\lambda_i}$, although I'm not sure if that is helpful.

I feel that I am forgetting a basic yet crucial fact, or that the statement is false as I have written it, and that I need to impose additional assumptions. Hints or solutions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: @jtms88 : It is standard to use \cap for things like $A\cap B$ or $A_1\cap\cdots\cap A_n$ and \bigcap for things like $\bigcap_{n=1}^N A_n$.  In particular, the positions of the subscripts and superscripts are different when the latter is used in a "displayed" as opposed to "inline" setting: $\displaystyle\bigcap_{n=1}^N A_n$.  (I edited your question accordingly.  Also, notice that I added \mid, which automatically provides proper spacing in things like $a\mid b$.) ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MorganO: In your example, $\bigcap_i \ker \lambda_i = \langle e_1, e_2 - e_3 \rangle$ is $2$-dimensional

Comment: @zcn: Of course -- thanks for pointing this out. Not sure where my brain went. I'll delete the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "basic abstract algebra" fact being alluded to is most likely (a weak form of) the Chinese Remainder Theorem:

**Proposition:** Let $X$ be a $k$-vector space, and $W_1, \ldots, W_n$ subspaces of $X$. Then the canonical map $X/\bigcap_{i=1}^n W_i \to \bigoplus_{i=1}^n X/W_i$ is injective.

In your situation, discarding any $\lambda_i : X \to k$ that are identically zero, set $W_i := \ker \lambda_i$, and $W := \bigcap_{i=1}^n W_i$. Then any map $X/W \to k$ is the restriction of a map $\bigoplus_{i=1}^n X/W_i \to k$, which is precisely a linear combination of the $\lambda_i$. 
$\DeclareMathOperator{\Hom}{\operatorname{Hom}}$

If you're familiar with exact sequences: the exact sequence $0 \to X/W \to \bigoplus_{i=1}^n X/W_i$ induces an exact sequence $\Hom_k(\bigoplus_{i=1}^n X/W_i, k) \to \Hom_k(X/W, k) \to 0$, and $\Hom_k(\bigoplus_{i=1}^n X/W_i, k) \cong \bigoplus_{i=1}^n \Hom_k(X/W_i, k) = k \langle \lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_n \rangle$.

Comment: The proposition mentioned works for any module and submodules, over any commutative ring